# Chartjs 2 - Stacked bar and unstacked line on same chart with same y axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've started using the latest beta of v2 of chart.js since I need to draw a chart that contains both a stacked bar chart and an unstacked line chart on the same chart.  Here's an example of what I need:

[image]

In this chart the lines are not stacked and are all showing their natural values but the bar chart is stacked and shows the combined total of the values (including some negative values).

I've managed to get the two charts drawn together but so far I've only succeeded in either having both charts stacked or I've had to use two separate y-axis which ends up with 2 scales.  There's an example of the separate y-axis in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jptabubm/):

```
yAxes: [{
    stacked: false,
    ticks: {
      beginAtZero: true
    }
  }, {
    id: "bar-y-axis",
    stacked: true,
    ticks: {
      beginAtZero: true
    },
    type: 'linear'
  }]
```

If I remove the first y-axis then I ended up with a single scale with the only problem being that the line chart is now stacked as well.

Is there any way to draw a chart like I need using chart.js?

Comment: I had this same issue and this answer resolved it. Hope this helps anyone. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42959474/chart-js-remove-stacking

Answer (score 25):

You can get this functionality with a combination of setting a different `yAxisID` (e.g. `yAxisID: "bar-stacked"`) to each of your datasets, and then adding a second `options.scales.yAxes` object.  So you would have this as a dataset:

```
{
  label: 'Promoters',
  backgroundColor: "#aad700",
  yAxisID: "bar-stacked",
  data: [
    50, 44, 52, 62, 48, 58, 59, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54
  ]
}
```

and then you would add an additional yAxes (the first one will be the collection of your line datasets [no `yAxisId` in the example below], the second will be all of the bars you want stacked):

```
yAxes: [{
  stacked: false,
  ticks: {
    beginAtZero: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 100
  }
}, {
  id: "bar-stacked",
  stacked: true,
  display: false, //optional if both yAxes use the same scale
  ticks: {
    beginAtZero: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 100
  },
  type: 'linear'
}]
```

Full example is as follows:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Stacked Bar Chart</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
  <style>
    canvas {
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width: 100%">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
  <script>
    var barChartData = {
      labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
      datasets: [{
        data: [
          50, 30, 60, 70, 80, 90, 95, 70, 90, 20, 60, 95
        ],
        type: 'line',
        label: 'This Year',
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        borderColor: "#70cbf4",
        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
        borderDash: [],
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
        lineTension: 0.3,
        pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
        pointBorderColor: "#70cbf4",
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 5,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#70cbf4",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "#70cbf4",
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 4,
        pointHitRadius: 10
      }, {
        data: [
          25, 40, 30, 70, 60, 50, 40, 70, 40, 80, 30, 90
        ],
        type: 'line',
        label: 'Last Year',
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        borderColor: "#737373",
        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
        borderDash: [10, 10],
        borderDashOffset: 0.0,
        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
        lineTension: .3,
        pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
        pointBorderColor: "#737373",
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 5,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#737373",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "#737373",
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 4,
        pointHitRadius: 10
      }, {
        label: 'Promoters',
        backgroundColor: "#aad700",
        yAxisID: "bar-y-axis",
        data: [
          50, 44, 52, 62, 48, 58, 59, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54
        ]
      }, {
        label: 'Passives',
        backgroundColor: "#ffe100",
        yAxisID: "bar-y-axis",
        data: [
          20, 21, 24, 25, 26, 17, 28, 19, 20, 11, 22, 33
        ]
      }, {
        label: 'Detractors',
        backgroundColor: "#ef0000",
        yAxisID: "bar-y-axis",
        data: [
          30, 35, 24, 13, 26, 25, 13, 31, 29, 37, 25, 13
        ]
      }]
    };

    window.onload = function() {
      var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
      window.myBar = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: barChartData,
        options: {
          title: {
            display: true,
            text: "Chart.js Bar Chart - Stacked"
          },
          tooltips: {
            mode: 'label'
          },
          responsive: true,
          scales: {
            xAxes: [{
              stacked: true,
            }],
            yAxes: [{
              stacked: false,
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 100
              }
            }, {
              id: "bar-y-axis",
              stacked: true,
              display: false, //optional
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 100
              },
              type: 'linear'
            }]
          }
        }
      });
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Useful answer but If you don't hardcode the min and max ticks then your line and stacked bar will not have 0 at the same place on the chart...

Comment: yes having two y-axis is very tricky if you want them to both scale the same - see other answer I linked to solve this better

Comment: Is there a way to synchronize the Y axis ranges that doesn't require forcing a min/max?

Answer (score 4):

Another answer here - you can set a 'stack' identifier for the data you want to be cumulative (i.e. just the bars), and turn off 'fill' on the line graphs to draw just as a line rather than mountain range

[Chart.js remove stacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42959474/chart-js-remove-stacking)

Answer (score 3):

You can set the stacked property on bar datasets, so lines don't stack.
Try something like this:

```
 data: {
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Line 1',
        data: [],
        backgroundColor: '#3788d8cc',
        borderColor: '#3788d8cc',
        fill: false
      }, {
        label: 'Stacked bar 1',
        data: [],
        backgroundColor: '#e51c23',
        borderColor: '#e51c23',
        type: 'bar',
        stack: 'bar-stacked'
      }, {
        label: 'Line 2',
        data: [],
        backgroundColor: '#ff9800',
        borderColor: '#ff9800',
        fill: false
      },
      {
        label: 'Stacked bar 2',
        data: [],
        type: 'bar',
        backgroundColor: '#3f51b5',
        borderColor: '#3f51b5',
        stack: 'bar-stacked'
      }],
      labels: [],
    },
    options: {
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      legend: {
        display: true
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          display: true
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          display: true
        }]
      }
    }
```